# JBoss isolated ear deployment problem - Ear modules isolated from each other

Tags: seam, classloader, jboss5.x, war, ear

We have an application that we package as an ear file.  We use seam in our application. We are using JBoss 5.1.0.GA. We found that there were class conflict problems with the jboss admin console because it uses seam.  So we decided to set ear deployment to isolated by setting the isolated property of the `EARClassLoaderDeployer` bean to true in the file:  `.../jboss-as/server/default/deployers/ear-deployer-jboss-beans.xml`.

When we did this we started to get `ClassNotFoundExceptions` within our app which was unexpected.  I thought that setting isolated ear deployment meant that modules within the ear could still share classes?

The class not found is an interface of an ejb.

Does anyone have any pointers on this problem?

A seam filter class from a seam library in `connect-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war` is trying to reference an EJB interface class in `connect-domain-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Our ear structure:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
lib/
bcprov-jdk15-140.jar
connect-domain-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
connect-esb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
connect-soap-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
connect-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar
joda-time-1.6.jar
lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar
lib/commons-lang-2.1.jar
lib/connect-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
lib/jasypt-1.6.jar
lib/jboss-el-1.0_02.CR4.jar
lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar
lib/saxon-9.1.0.8.jar
lib/saxon-dom-9.1.0.8.jar
log4j.xml
META-INF/application.xml
META-INF/jboss-app.xml
not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9.jar
opensaml-2.1.0.jar
openws-1.1.0.jar
paconnect-ds.xml
paconnectDeploy.sh
velocity-1.5.jar
xmltooling-1.0.1.jar
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/pa.connect/
META-INF/maven/pa.connect/connect-ear/
META-INF/maven/pa.connect/connect-ear/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/pa.connect/connect-ear/pom.properties
```

Our stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pa.connect.domain.ConnectDomainService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:292)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveProxyClass(ObjectInputStream.java:675)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1530)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1492)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.getTreeStructureToRestore(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:200)
    at javax.faces.render.ResponseStateManager.getState(ResponseStateManager.java:226)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreView(AjaxStateManager.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:311)
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamViewHandler.restoreView(SeamViewHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.restoreView(FaceletViewHandler.java:316)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:179)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:86)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
15:13:25,442 SEVERE [lifecycle] JSF1054: (Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1, View ID: ) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@7a7f72e0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by making a classloader repository that the war and ear share.  And changed my ear to include JSF libs that were previously being provided by JBoss.